# 4 year old son peeing on himself

Tags: potty-training

My 4 year old son is very very smart, but he pees on himself at home.

Sometimes when we go out he goes to the bathroom in public. Some days he wets the bed at night at home, other days he gets up middle of the night and go potty. During the day time sometimes he goes to the bathroom busy or not and other times he doesn’t.

He does go to daycare and doesn’t pee on himself there. Also he goes to his grandma house just about every weekend if not every other weekend and sometimes for a week at a time and never pees over there. I can’t understand what he’s doing over there that he just can’t seem to do at home to not pee on himself. I’ve tried asking him why does he pee on himself all he say is "I don't know".

I tried timeout, tried taking everything away, no tv no toys and playing. I did recently have a 1 year old so that definitely could be why he’s doing this because it has been about 2 years give or take that he has been doing this so he’s not that little baby no more. I also have a 10 year old.

I’ve tried everything. I took him to the doctor to see a specialist and they said everything is normal inside wise. I just can’t understand why sometimes he goes and most times he don’t and don’t care if he wet himself or not I don’t know what else to do I’ve tried so many different things any suggestions plz.

Comment: Could you edit this so it easier to read? This is just one long sentence so quite difficult to parse.

Comment: I've edited this to make it easier to read. Can you have a look through and see if I've got anything wrong? If I have then click on "Edit" under the question and you can fix any mistakes.

Comment: "Everything" is unhelpful when you describe what you've done. For example, I see only punitive measures. Have you tried rewards? Sticker charts? "Bribes"? Talking to his grandmother to see what they do differently? Timers and reminders? Special time with you if he goes, say, a week without wetting himself? If you've tried *everything*, including consulting his doctor about this, then there's nothing we can offer that you haven't tried, and you just need to be patient, gracious, be glad it doesn't happen at school, and don't make it into a bigger deal than it is. He'll outgrow it.

Comment: Have you considered that your kid isn't actually peeing themselves intentionally, and that bribing them, punishing them and that stuff isn't exactly going to help here? Seriously, when I was that age I peed myself a lot, but never because I didn't *want* to go to the bathroom. You said your kid is smart, maybe trust them a little more when they say "I don't know" and try to get more information instead of taking their toys away.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, wetting the bed at age 4 is normal (if annoying for your laundry). Doctors aren't worries about night time dryness until age 7 or so. Depending on the frequency, maybe he needs night nappies still, there are also special protective/absorbent sheets and covers to make your life easier when it comes to laundry.

For daytime, clearly he can do it and stay dry all day, so I do see your frustration.
Are you expecting him to be completely self directed when it comes to toileting, deciding by himself to stop doing whatever fun activity he's currently doing and going to the bathroom without encouragement? As that might be a bit beyond him! I have to intervene when I see my nearly 4 year old clearly needs the toilet and remind him he doesn't want wet trousers etc to get him to decide to go.
What are his grandparents or school doing differently?

I would also say at that age, the 'punishment' must fit the crime, that is, be a natural consequence. The natural result of wetting himself is that he has to help clean up himself, and the environment. Which is boring. So he has to sort his clean clothes, put the wet and dirty ones away, wipe himself down, and help you clean up the floor etc. He can now immediately see that the decision to *not* go to the toilet meant he lost out on play time straight away. Keep your response neutral and not shaming (State facts, "oh dear, your trousers are wet, now we have to stop playing and clean up", "you pee in the potty/toilet, then you don't get wet trousers"). You're also helping him learn to be a responsible human with the skills to clean up after himself.